# Storing each element from each RDD to a new List

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to store each element from each rdd into a new list. I can **print the elements** but I could **not store elements** in list or even having a string variable.

The is the code below:

```
...
    var hashtags = joined_d.map(x => ((x._1, x._2._1._1, x._2._2, 
    x._2._1._4), 
    getHashTags(x._2._1._4))).
    transform(rdd => rdd.map{case (x, list) => if(list.length > 0) 
    list.map(k => (k, (x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, 1))) 
    else List((x._1.toString, (x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, 0))) })
```

Now when **storing** the elements like:

```
    val arr = new ArrayBuffer[String]();
    var hashtags_pair = hashtags.foreachRDD(rdd => 
    rdd.foreach(l => l.foreach(x =>  arr += x._1)))
```

Then **printing** the values out:

```
arr.foreach(println) // Not working
```

But when printing the values straight **without storing** it like:

```
var hashtags_pair = hashtags.foreachRDD(rdd => 
rdd.foreach(l => l.foreach(x => println(x._1))) // It's working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't store the output of a map in an array. The reason is the RDD is a distributed dataset and it executes the map operation in different executors in parallel. Now the driver sends only the closure of the map operation to the executors for execution.

Here the declared array variable is a local to the driver and it can't be send to all the executors.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.